A pop pop boat heated with a self-contained heat source and run in a superfluid appears to show a preferred frame
Suppose there is a pop pop boat but the water is replaced by a superfluid and the candle is replaced by a radioactive heat source
The pop pop boat should accelerate forwards;
Now let’s imaging a second observer moving in the same direction as the pop pop boat is accelerating.
This observer observes a decrease in energy, thus the frame in which the superfluid is stationary appears to be favoured

Do you have a physics-related question to ask here?

What the hell is "modified pop pop boat"? Please define your details or else it's nonsense.

Please read the full question,rather than only the title

@Harrychink still, a) it's not clear what your question is and b) it's never explained what a pop pop boat is. Also, it's not clear what you mean by a "decrease in energy", and accelerating reference frames aren't necessarily inertial anyways

The second reference frame is not accelerated, but rather is travelling in the direction of the pop pop boat but at a constant speed.

@Harrychink the modifications do not appear to change anything, and it is not at all clear why you think there is a decrease in energy in any frame. Both energy and momentum are conserved in all inertial frames.

What if instead of a pop pop boat, you had a glunkerdoodle?

Making the medium a superfluid doesn't seem to change much here.   It still has to enter the vessel and then be ejected.
Because the ejected fluid will have some speed relative to the boat, the boat will reach a maximum speed relative to the reservoir.   This happens when the momentum of the ejected fluid is equal and opposite to the momentum of the fluid re-entering (in the frame of the boat).
The observer should consider not just the change in KE of the boat, but the change in KE of the fluid as well.

Since the water is just pulsing in and out I would expect no net motion of the fluid outside of the boat

@Harrychink if there is no motion of the water (or superfluid), then by definition the boat-water system has gained momentum from nothing. The boat can only gain momentum by pushing on the water.

@Harrychink that isn’t how pop pop boats work. The water does not just pulse in and out. There is net motion of the fluid.

How can a pipe sealed at one end create net fluid motion?

@Harrychink see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_pop_boat and if you have additional questions then ask as a full question

@dale i do not understand why the momentum of the fluid leaving is not transferred back to the boat, resulting in a non operational pop pop boat
